# JavaScript Google Map Coordinate Validation

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a form where you can select a point on the map, and it populates lat and lon textboxes, or you can enter the coordinates yourself.

I need to add validation to make sure the user enters valid ranges, but I am not sure if I have the right RegEx.  Here is the method I am using:

```
var regex_coords = "[-]?[0-9]*[.]{0,1}[0-9]";

// ...

valid_coords: function (number) {
if (number.match(regex_coords) && !isNaN(Number(number))) {
    $("#btnSaveResort").removeAttr("disabled");
    return true;
} else {
    $("#btnSaveResort").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    return false;
}
},
```

This function returns false no matter what I have entered in the textboxes.

Any suggestions on a better way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457522/latitude-longitude-regular-expression

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Latitude and longitude have different ranges: latitude is (-90,90) and longitude is (-180,180), so using a single regex is not really going to work. You might also want to check that the latitude can be plotted on the map — which means that it needs to lie in the range (-85,85) approximately. Or you might want to limit the range to a bounding rectangle containing a particular area.

Why not explicitly test the ranges?

```
function inrange(min,number,max){
    if ( !isNaN(number) && (number >= min) && (number <= max) ){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    };
}
```

You can then tailor your code for what you want. Presumably you only want to enable the save button if both latitude and longitude are valid.

```
valid_coords: function(number_lat,number_lng) {
    if (inrange(-90,number_lat,90) && inrange(-180,number_lng,180)) {
        $("#btnSaveResort").removeAttr("disabled");
        return true;
    }
    else {
        $("#btnSaveResort").attr("disabled","disabled");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was wondering about the lat and lon ranges, so I changed my code over to what you have.  The problem now is that it seems to be running the valid_coords function multiple times, the first few times with the correct values then an Object is being passed.  I'm trying to trace it down, then I'll post my results and hopefully mark this one checked. Thanks!

Comment: Looks good! I had another function calling the same valid function but was passing the textbox, not the textbox value when the map is changed.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking into regex, completely forgot I can check it with a method like this!

Answer (score 0):

Your regex looks incorrect. Try:

```
var regex_coords = /\-?[0-9]+[\.]{0,1}[0-9]*/;
```