# Enable checkbox if the correct coordinates is entered

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to enable a checkbox if the text field has the valid coordinates but it will not work as I want it to work. I'm asking you know, what have I done wrong?

[Demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S8r8u/10/).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: select jquery on the list of frameworks first http://jsfiddle.net/justelnegro/S8r8u/5/

Comment: My mistake. I have edited my demo now :) Same problem though

Comment: You regex rule is failing. Check [this][1] out.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10917867/javascript-google-map-coordinate-validation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Event types are separated by space not commas
2. I replaced the RegExp constructor with the alternate declaration and it works. Not completely sure why.

http://jsfiddle.net/S8r8u/31/

Comment: There seems to be something wrong. I can't even properly paste the code here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on the RegExp. It doesn't seem to be matching but your event won't fire because the jQuery syntax for multiple events is separation by space not comma.

```
$('input[name="textfield-coordinates"]').on('keyup change paste', function() {

});
```

[jQuery on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Thanks, but Thomas has already answered with the correct solution :)